# What is this block I keep seeing in Tekkit with Sips and Sjin?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I've watched nearly every episode in the [Tekkit with Sips and Sjin YouTube series](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0B7E58C6AE7CD2CB), and I keep seeing this particular oddly-colored block amongst the stone bricks that make up the bases of their facility buildings. I've taken a still image from their [Christmas Special](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJezMI2ibH0&list=LLrpRQIbMMaqiwgKJH6jluyQ) as an example:

[image: There's monsters about and the power is out]

The block appears to have a stone brick texture, but each of the 4 bricks in the block is a different color. I've never heard them make any mention of what this was or how they made it, and I've never come across it in the Technic item inventory. What is this? Is it an actual block you can create, or a special texture for some other block in the texture pack that they use?

Comment: probably wool cut into cubes and put together to form that, but idk if it isnt

Comment: @Paralytic RP2 microblocks used like that almost always show a lighting bug that I'm not seeing in the screenshot. I'm betting it's a custom texture on something like the chiseled stone brick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is part of how the [Sphax PureBDcraft](http://bdcraft.net/) texture pack generates the textures. I think it throws in a different texture every so often to break up the monotony and add a little decoration. The same happens with the grass texture. A flower texture pops up here and there on the grass. I don't know what other block textures do that but I've noticed those two.

Comment: Aha, so there's multiple textures per block type. Now that I think about it, that also explains why zombies and creepers show up with varying textures in their videos as well.

Comment: Aha. That's a feature of OptiFine, which texture packs can use to add variant textures.

Answer (score 1):

It's just normal stone brick.  I was building a power station the other day, and while laying out the floor, one of the bricks I put down looked like the screenshot.  Removing it and replacing it didn't work (it still showed multi-color).

Comment: And this was using the same texture pack and mods?

Answer (score -1):

It's a glitch with sphax connected textures. Had the same glitch.

Comment: Any sufficiently awesome glitch is indistinguishable from a feature. Although reading the answers user49095 and (possibly?) vmizzle provided, sounds like it *is* a feature of Sphax.

Answer (score -2):

It's just wool in the texture pack they use

Comment: I don't think it's the little block he's pointing at.